# How do I add 1000 to an employee whose salary is less than 2000?

Tags: oracle10g

How do I add 1000 to an employee in an employee table whose salary is less than 2000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your table definition, but something like this to give everyone a pay rise if they have a salary less than 2000:

```
UPDATE employee 
SET salary = salary + 1000 
WHERE salary < 2000
```

If you want to find out what their salary would be with another 1000:-

```
SELECT salary + 1000
FROM employee
WHERE salary < 2000
```

Comment: can i get with out UPDATE, IN A SINGLE LINE 
LIKE THIS..... WHERE SAL<2000 THAN SAL+1000
SORRY AS I AM NEW TO THIS I WANT ONLY IN SELECT STATMENTS

Comment: Do you want to update the table, or just get the value with 1000 added to it?

Comment: i  JUST WANT TO ADD IT .. IF THE SALARY IS LESS THAN 2000... NOT TO UPDATE
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

You can add by using following sql statement.but i have tested in Mysql its running fine.you can convert according to oracle syntax.Sql statement is

```
UPDATE employee SET salary = salary +1000 WHERE salary <2000
```